# In INSERT SELECT Query of Oracle, It is changed DATE format

Tags: oracle

```
INSERT INTO T1 ( ..., CONTRACT_DATE)
SELECT ..., CONTRACT_DATE
  FROM T2
 WHERE ...
```

In `T1`, `CONTRACT_DATE` stands as  '`2017-12-12`'
But in `T2`, Transferred 'CONTRACT_DATE`stands as '`12-DEC-12`'.

Event if I change the query like

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CONTRACT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

It was same.

What can I do for the same format between `T1` and `T2`?

Comment: What is the **data type** of `contract_date` in each table? Don't guess, don't speculate; even if you know for sure, please run `describe t1` and `describe t2` and post here what they report. Then we can take it from there.

Comment: Some sample data from the two tables would also be nice.

Comment: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CONTRACT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')` makes **no** sense whatsoever if `contract_date` is a `date` column.

Comment: @mathguy It was my misunderstanding.. Event if the session format of nls_date_format was not 'YYYY-MM-DD', It doesn't matter. I was sure that T1's column was DATE type, As you guessed, It was varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like oyu have one table with date as text (e.g. `VARCHAR`) and the other with format as `DATE`. Now the way you see the `DATE` fields depends from the tool you use.

I guess you should play with your `SESSION` parameters:

```
Alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';
```

E.g. if you use `sqlplus`:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM T1;
BA 14/06/2016
FM 31/05/2016
TP 15/06/2016

SQL>     Alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL>  SELECT * FROM T1;
BA 2016-06-14
FM 2016-05-31
TP 2016-06-15
```

Now from PLSQL Developer or another IDE: this should be found in your preferences.

Comment: The correct answer, is to fix the data types. Just bite the bullet and do it now, otherwise more problems will ensue.

Comment: @BobC - that's easy for you to say, but frequently harder to execute in existing applications.

Comment: @APC  Yup, I realize that. However it does not make it any less correct :). Of course, if you only have a 14 row EMP table it will not make a blind bit of difference. But it's important that people realize that to get the best out of the product (which they pay a lot of money for), they should learn to use it properly. Don't by a Ferrari and then leave it in 2nd gear. So maybe this app never gets fixed. But hopefully someone reading this thread my learn something for the next app.